# Gitkraken malformed url - on pull Gitkraken edits the remote url and puts ".git" on the end

Tags: ssh, gitkraken, malformed

### Gitkraken malformed url on pull

Gitkraken creates a malformed url when doing a pull edits to remote urls by adding a username and also appends ".git" to the end of the url making it malformed.  Our remote repository urls don't have a ".git" on the end.

### Example (no username or .git on the url for our Azure DevOps repos):

```
git remote -v
origin ssh://example.company.net/CollectionName/AppName/_git/repository.name (fetch)
origin ssh://example.company.net/CollectionName/AppName/_git/repository.name (push)
```

The moment any developer does a pull in Gitkraken it then asks for a username with a "Submit" button.  Once that is done on the first one it says successful.  Then after that, the next pull gives the error:

```
Pull Failed
malformed URL
```

If we look at the remote list again.  Now it has been edited and adds a username and ".git" to the end making it invalid

```
git remote -v
origin ssh://username@example.company.net/CollectionName/AppName/_git/repository.name.git (fetch)
origin ssh://username@example.company.net/CollectionName/AppName/_git/repository.name.git (push)
```

Comment: I contacted GitKraken support and they informed me this sounded like a known issue when using Azure DevOps repository in GitKraken.  After the initial push, go and edit your remote URL back to the expected URL and then try again. It should succeed.  GitKraken should not try to modify the URL again on subsequent operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this behaviour is not configurable (and should be reported to [GitKraken support](https://www.gitkraken.com/contact)), you might consider, as a temporary workaround, adding symlinks to your remote repositories

On the remote side:

```sh
cd CollectionName/AppName/_git/
ln -s repository.name repository.name.git
```

That would help you keep using GitKraken while accessing your remote repositories.